# Generating a calculated column based on "passed" rows values

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm looking for a way to add a column to my query, and it's based on the SUM of "passed" rows values of a column, something like this:

```
DECLARE @Remain int = 0;
SELECT price, @Remain += price AS remain FROM Invoice
```

The result must be like this:

```
price  remain
-----  ------
100    100
200    300
50     350
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a version that supports windowing functions, then you can do this:
(I added an id for ordering the data).

```
declare @Invoice table (id int, price int)
insert into @invoice(id,price) values(1,100),(2,200),(3,50)


SELECT price, sum(price) over(order by id) AS remain From @invoice
```

Result:

```
price   remain
100 100
200 300
50  350
```

Comment: You should add a comment that this running total behaviour works because there is a default frame clause equivalent to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.